# Uniform continuity supremum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the [User's Guide to Viscosity Solutions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9207212v1.pdf), it is claimed at the top of page 31 that

> If $f\colon \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a uniformly continuous function, there exists a positive constant $K$ such that $$\textstyle{\sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}}}\left\{f(x)-f(y)-K\left|x-y\right|\right\} < \infty.$$

Denoting by $\omega$ the modulus of continuity of $f$,

\begin{align*}
\textstyle{\sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}}}\left\{f(x)-f(y)-K\left|x-y\right|\right\}
& \leq \textstyle{\sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}}}\left\{\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|-K\left|x-y\right|\right\} \\
& \leq \textstyle{\sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}}}\left\{\omega(\left|x-y\right|)-K\left|x-y\right|\right\} \\
& \leq \textstyle{\sup_{t\in[0,\infty)}}\left\{\omega(t)-Kt\right\}.
\end{align*}

**I am not sure how to proceed since $\omega$ is arbitrary**. Any help is greatly appreciated.

A special case that establishes the result for a large family of functions (including Hölder continuous functions with exponent $\alpha\leq 1$) is given below.

---

Suppose there exists constants $a$, $b$, and $t_0>0$ such that $\omega$ is continuous on $[0,t_0]$ and for all $t>t_0$, $\omega(t)\leq at+b$ (i.e., the *family of modulii that are "eventually sublinear"*).

Taking $K=a$, it follows that if $t>t_0$, $\omega(t)-Kt \leq b$. Meanwhile, the maximum of $\omega(t) - Kt$ on $[0,t_0]$ is attained at some point $t^\star\in[0,t_0]$. Therefore,

$$\textstyle{\sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}}}\left\{f(x)-f(y)-K\left|x-y\right|\right\} \leq \max\left\{b,\omega(t^\star) - Kt^\star\right\}<\infty$$

Comment: Did you prove it for $d=1?$

Comment: @zhw.: I have not. Does the dimensionality factor into it?

Comment: It's a bit easier if $d=1$ but it may give you the idea for $d>1.$

Comment: @zhw: I am drawing a blank. Could I trouble you for another hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start: Take $d=2$ for example. We know that there is $C$ such that $|x-y|\le 1 \implies |f(y)-f(x)|\le C.$ Look at $(m,n) \in \mathbb N^2.$ Then

$$f(m,n) - f(0,0) = (f(m,n)-f(m,n-1)) + (f(m,n-1)-f(m,n-2)) + \cdots + (f(m,1) - f(m,0))$$ $$ + (f(m,0)-f(m-1,0)) + \cdots + (f(1,0)-f(0,0)).$$

This is $\le C(m+n).$ And $m+n \le \sqrt 2 \sqrt {m^2 + n^2}$ $ = \sqrt 2|(m,n)-(0,0)|.$ Thus we have

$$f(m,n) - f(0,0) \le  C\sqrt 2|(m,n)-(0,0)|.$$

That looks good, no? See if you can use this idea for the full proof.

Comment: How do we know there exists $C$ such that $|x-y|\leq 1 \implies |f(x)-f(y)|\leq C$? Uniform continuity gives $\forall C > 0 \colon \exists \delta > 0 \colon |x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < C$. What if $\delta$ is always less than one?

Comment: Take any closed ball $B$ of radius $1.$ Choose $N\in \mathbb N$ such that square $2/N<\delta$ (your $\delta$). If $x,y \in B,$ then we can divide the line segment $[x,y]$ into $N$ succesive line segments. Each of these line segments has length $\le 2/N< \delta.$ Then we can estimate $f(y) - f(x)$ by chaining together differences, sort of like what I did above. We get $f(y) - f(x) \le N\cdot 1.$ Take $C=N.$

Comment: The word "square" in the second sentence of my comment should be deleted.